# Can't add label to python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

When I'm pressing a button on my python form I want to add new label and place it on the grid. When I'm pressing the button, nothing happen.

My code is attached:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        topiclbl = Label(self,text = 'Enter topic for search',font=(12))
        topiclbl.grid()
        topictxt = Text(self,height=1, width=30,font=(12))
        topictxt.grid()
        searchbtn = Button(self,text = 'Search Videos',command='search')
        searchbtn.grid()

    def search(self):

        message = 'Searching...'
        self.topictxt.insert(0.0,message)
        searchlbl = Label(self,text = message,font=(12))
        searchlbl.grid()


root = Tk()
root.title('Video Search')
root.geometry('600x600')
app=Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues in your code:

You are referencing in your `command` argument to the wrong method name, it should be:

`searchbtn = Button(self,text = 'Search Videos',command=self.search)`

Plus, you havesome attribute issues:

You cannot access `topictxt` you defined in `create_widget` method outside this method, unless you make it as instance attribute, this way:

`self.topiclbl = Label(self,text = 'Enter topic for search',font=(12))` ... same goes for the rest. So as a fix to that:

```
class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.topiclbl = Label(self,text = 'Enter topic for search',font=(12))
        self.topiclbl.grid()
        self.topictxt = Text(self,height=1, width=30,font=(12))
        self.topictxt.grid()
        self.searchbtn = Button(self,text = 'Search Videos',command=self.search)
        self.searchbtn.grid()

    def search(self):

        message = 'Searching...'
        self.topictxt.insert(0.0,message)
        self.searchlbl = Label(self,text = message,font=(12))
        self.searchlbl.grid()
```

Another way is to use `lambda` to pass the object(label) you want:

```
class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        topiclbl = Label(self,text = 'Enter topic for search',font=(12))
        topiclbl.grid()
        topictxt = Text(self,height=1, width=30,font=(12))
        topictxt.grid()
        searchbtn = Button(self,text = 'Search Videos',command=lambda: self.search(topictxt))
        searchbtn.grid()

    def search(self, wdgt):

        message = 'Searching...'
        wdgt.insert(0.0,message)
        searchlbl = Label(self,text = message,font=(12))
        searchlbl.grid()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass an actual function to `Button` when you create it

e.g.

```
searchbtn = Button(self,text = 'Search Videos',command=self.search)
```